# Different(?) Interrogatives? Information on Interrogatives?

Tags: questions

I've read a complete interrogative requests an auxiliary verb, argument, verb, and maybe other arguments.

> When do you run?

I've read you may not use an auxiliary verb to get a complete interrogative.

> Do you run?

I guess, this may seem like a different grammatical, complete interrogative, to, maybe, get you a yes, or no, using a verb compliment(?), argument, and verb. Which, as a complete declarative may look like *You do run.*, which may seem different from *You run.*, a complete imperative(?).

That first interrogative may get you information, that second may mostly get you a yes, or no. Do these different(?) interrogatives get called different things?

> Have you any importance, here?

Which one may get this called?

Answer (score 1):

Questions which ask for information beyond a **yes or no answer** are called

> **Open-ended questions**

yes-or-no answer questions are called

> **Closed-ended questions**

Some examples can be found [**here**](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-open-ended-and-closed-ended-questions.html)